# View Controller doesn't find a func member

Tags: swift

I'm getting this error:

> Value of type 'DiscountVC' has no member 'calculateTotal'. And I have no clue why. Basically, I'm trying to make this calculator:

[image]

It should work as soon as you insert any value on the `discountTF`. Also, I have some pre-discounted buttons that just edit the discount value. The `subtotalLabel` value comes from another `ViewController`. For testing purposes, I'm using an initial value of 999.9.

```swift
import UIKit

class DiscountVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var numericKeyboardView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var subtotalLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var discountTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var totalLabel: UILabel!

    var subtotal : Double = 999.9
    var discount : Double = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        addKeyboard(view: numericKeyboardView)
        subtotal = 999.9
        discount = 0.0
        discountTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.calculateTotal(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    func calculateTotal() {
        let totalDouble = Double(subtotal) - Double(discountTF.text!)!
        totalLabel.text = String(totalDouble)
    }

    func addKeyboard(view: UIView) {
        let numericKeyboard = KeyboardVC(nibName: "NumericKeyboardVC", bundle: nil)
        view.addSubview(numericKeyboard.view)
        addChild(numericKeyboard)
    }

    @IBAction func fivePercentedButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        discount = Double(discountTF.text!)! * 0.05
        discountTF.text = "\(discount)"
        print(discount)
    }

    @IBAction func tenPercentButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        discount = Double(discountTF.text!)! * 0.1
        discountTF.text = "\(discount)"
        print(discount)
    }

    @IBAction func fifteenPercentButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        discount = Double(discountTF.text!)! * 0.15
        discountTF.text = "\(discount)"
        print(discount)    
    }

    @IBAction func twentyPercentButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        discount = Double(discountTF.text!)! * 0.2
        discountTF.text = "\(discount)"
        print(discount)    
    }

    @IBAction func goButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
@objc func calculateTotal(_ tex:UITextField){ --- }
```

Comment: This fixed it. Just one thing, I put text instead of tex in it. Thanks!